# Mongo Aggregate Multiple Groups and Sums

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a flat data structure that looks like this:

```
{
 state: String,
 caseA: Number,
 caseB: Number,
 caseC: Number
}
```

I want to aggregate and sum each case in total, and then I want the sum of each case by state.

I can do the first part, but not sure how to do the second grouping.

```
{$group: {
 _id: null,
 total_caseA: {$sum: "$caseA"},
 total_caseB: {$sum: "$caseB"},
 total_caseC: {$sum: "$caseC"},
}}
```

I would like the results to look like this:

```
{
 total_caseA: <sum of all caseA across all states>,
 total_caseB: <sum of all caseB across all states>,
 total_caseC: <sum of all caseB across all states>,
 states: [
  "AK": {
   caseA: <sum of caseA for state>,
   caseB: <sum of caseB for state>,
   caseB: <sum of caseC for state>,
  },
  "CA": {
   caseA: <sum of caseA for state>,
   caseB: <sum of caseB for state>,
   caseB: <sum of caseC for state>,
  },
  ...
 ]
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

[**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) will give you two different arrays one for `total` cases counts and one with the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by `states` and its cases count... In states count you have to push all the values into an array to make values as keys using [**`$arrayToObject`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)... And finally [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) with the zeroth elements of both the arrays will finalize your output

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "total": [
      { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "total_caseA": { "$sum": "$caseA" },
        "total_caseB": { "$sum": "$caseB" },
        "total_caseC": { "$sum": "$caseC" }
      }}
    ],
    "states": [
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$state",
        "total_caseA": { "$sum": "$caseA" },
        "total_caseB": { "$sum": "$caseB" },
        "total_caseC": { "$sum": "$caseC" }
      }},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "data": {
          "$push": {
            "k": "$_id",
            "v": {
              "total_caseA": { "$sum": "$total_caseA" },
              "total_caseB": { "$sum": "$total_caseB" },
              "total_caseC": { "$sum": "$total_caseC" }
            }
          }
        }
      }},
      { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" } } }
    ]
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$total" },
  { "$addFields": { "total.states": "$states" } },
  { "$project": { "states": 0 } },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$total" } }
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "states": [
      {
        "AK": {
          "total_caseA": 1,
          "total_caseB": 2,
          "total_caseC": 3
        },
        "CA": {
          "total_caseA": 2,
          "total_caseB": 4,
          "total_caseC": 6
        }
      }
    ],
    "total_caseA": 3,
    "total_caseB": 6,
    "total_caseC": 9
  }
]
```

[MongoPlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JmCZgF6X47J)

Comment: This works really well.  Just one thing, how can I arrange the result object like this: [ {"_id": null,
    "total_caseA": 3,
    "total_caseB": 6,
    "total_caseC": 9}, states: { "AK": {
      "total_caseA": 1,
      "total_caseB": 2,
      "total_caseC": 3
    },
    "CA": {
      "total_caseA": 2,
      "total_caseB": 4,
      "total_caseC": 6
    }}}

Comment: Basically I want the states nested in the output object under "states"

Comment: Updated the answer have a look

Comment: It's perfect. It would have taken me days to figure this out.  Thank you!